# Why is the FTL service offline and the DNS service not running?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-hole

Firstly, I'm pretty aware of technology and how it works but I am no network engineer and very new to Linux/Raspberry Pi.

I just installed Raspbian then Pi-Hole and got the ad blocker working fine. The Raspberry Pi did a pretty big update after the fresh install and asked to reboot; I said no.

My router does not allow me to specify a DNS address, which I wanted to put my Pi's address in, instead of putting in the DNS into every device. Also, WiFi...

Anyway, I wanted to use the DHCP server in PiHole. Disabled DHCP on router, turned on DHCP server on Pi-Hole and thought I'd to a re-start because of the update the day before.

Note, ad-blocker was running fine for 1 day (yesterday).

Today, after a re-boot, The FTL is offline and the DNS service is not running.

No matter how much I try to turn everything back to how it was (DHCP server ON on router, OFF on PiHole), I just can't seem to get the DNS service running...?

Comment: What is 'FTL'? Full Truck Load? https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/FTL

Comment: I'm going to be honest... I don't know? It says it on the PiHole dashboard.

Comment: Likely it's https://github.com/pi-hole/FTL

Comment: Hmm... Very strange. Came back home from work today and it's working now? I don't know.